# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 crash on UIScrollView pinch gesture

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, exc-bad-access

My app has a UIScrollView with some items on it (such as UITextField), and for the most part, when the view loads with this scroll view, I am able to pinch to zoom in and out and it works fine.

However, sometimes I get some messages when I zoom in and out in the console that look like this:

```
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of __NSArrayM
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of NSShadow
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of __NSCFString
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of __NSCFType
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of UIButtonContent
```

And other times I get a crash that always looks like this:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x3b8155b6 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 22, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4)
    frame #0: 0x3b8155b6 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 22
    frame #1: 0x3552e9d4 QuartzCore`CALayerGetSuperlayer + 92
    frame #2: 0x357c0e5e UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) containsView:] + 34
    frame #3: 0x358eb3d4 UIKit`-[UITextSelectionView affectedByScrollerNotification:] + 140
    frame #4: 0x35a5b394 UIKit`-[UITextSelectionView scaleWillChange:] + 24
    frame #5: 0x338c7036 CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 1426
    frame #6: 0x341dd598 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
    frame #7: 0x341e105a Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 30
    frame #8: 0x35910bea UIKit`-[UIScrollView _updatePinchGestureForState:] + 946
    frame #9: 0x3589bd88 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 128
    frame #10: 0x358633f4 UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 392
    frame #11: 0x35a50a38 UIKit`___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0543 + 48
    frame #12: 0x3578782e UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 218
    frame #13: 0x35786292 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 1274
    frame #14: 0x357911e6 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 766
    frame #15: 0x35790db2 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 90
    frame #16: 0x3577e800 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 380
    frame #17: 0x3577e11a UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
    frame #18: 0x374725a2 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 590
    frame #19: 0x374721d2 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 34
    frame #20: 0x3394b172 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
    frame #21: 0x3394b116 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
    frame #22: 0x33949f98 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1384
    frame #23: 0x338bcebc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    frame #24: 0x338bcd48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    frame #25: 0x374712ea GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 74
    frame #26: 0x357d2300 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1120
    frame #27: 0x000134a4 MyApp`main(argc=3, argv=0x2fdefc68) + 48 at main.m:14
    frame #28: 0x00013470 MyApp`start + 40
```

My app uses ARC, and I have tried to run with zombies turned on, in which case the app just crashes and Instruments does not show any issues.

Any ideas as to what could be going on or what to do to chase down this issue?

EDIT: Per Steve's suggestion, I went back in and rechecked it with zombies turned on, and as it turns out, I must have done something incorrectly on the first time around. Now, when I run on the simulator with Instruments looking for zombies, I do get a zombie showing up when I try to dismiss the modal dialog that contains the UIScrollView that contains the controls. Here is a screen capture of the Instruments when the zombie appears:

[image: Zombieland]

What's maddening here is that I have to open and close the modal many times before I get a crash or a zombie showing up. And that I do not see any of my own code showing up in the Object Summary History for the zombie object.

Comment: To my mind, it appears that somehow the layer attached to UITextSelectionView is being deallocated prematurely. What do you have to do in order to trigger the crash? Are you doing anything strange with custom layers? It's possible that you might find something useful by adding a breakpoint to the dealloc method: `br s -n "-[UITextSelectionView dealloc]"`. You could also try doing the same to CALayer, although I suspect there will be a lot of breakpoints involved with that one. That said, this is an absolute guess.

Comment: Furthermore, it appears you have inadvertantly leaked the name of the app you are working on; I'm definitely sure my marketing guys would have something disparaging to say about that, but it depends on your firm.

Comment: Another idea: Are you /absolutely/ sure you turned zombies on? Are you sure you turned them on for the right target? Are you sure you turned them on for the correct target? You should be able to force a crash with something like `NSString* a = @"a"; CFRelease(__bridge a); [a length];` - see if this shows up in the zombies instruments.

Comment: (A second CFRelease might be necessary on the above; not entirely sure about the semantics of __bridge).

Comment: Steve: Thanks for the comments. I was not able to get your simple example to trigger a zombie, but did edit the question to include some more information that I found after reexamining to make sure that the scheme was set up correctly.

Comment: It's possible your code is still triggering these events somehow. I'm not sure if you're aware of this so forgive me for a redundant comment if so, but you can view the callstack for each of those events by clicking the right-hand menu option in the "View" section of the menu bar in Instruments. Perhaps this might provide some insight?

Comment: I am also facing this problem. My app also uses ARC and I am using a UITableView with custom cells using storyboard. When I leave the view that has TableView and returns back I get this message. Any clue how to solve it?

Comment: Mr. 17: I found out how to fix the problem I was having. Unfortunately, I do not believe that my solution will help you with your dilemma.

Comment: Hi @SteveRukuts and BP, I am getting same crash but I didn't override removeFromSuperView method. If you have any other solution plz provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the UIView contained in my scroll view that I was adding my own items to was overriding the removeFromSuperview method. When I went into that method and added the line

```
[self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

before the `[super removeFromSuperview]` call, it seems to work without crashing now.

Comment: I have same problem, but I didn't override removeFromSuperview method. Can you guess what will be my problem?